# Any advice for a class that has prerequisites?

Tags: preparation

I'm taking a higher math class because I'm a math major. The class is called Partial Differential Equations. I was wondering if I should just use the first week to review the prerequisites because the prerequisites are classes that I had some difficulty understanding.

But just in general i was asking just in a general if there was any good advice on taking a class with a prerequisite. Should I review the prereqs? Advice?

Comment: If you aren't solid on the prerequisites, then yes, reviewing them might be worthwhile. Ask the prof, or students who have taken or TA'd that class, whether there are particular area you should focus on.

Comment: You know, there are math classes that don't build so tightly on the previous classes as PDE's does, and that don't have as many prereqs as PDE's do (linear algebra, 3 semesters of calculus, ODEs).  If there is a fun class available with fewer prereqs, such as probability or graph theory, that might be a better option for you -- unless your future work interests might require you to get more solid with the material in the prereqs, and the professor happens to be outstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should be quite careful before taking a class with prerequisites, especially if you find the prerequisites difficult to understand.

Usually, most Professors will assume that you know the pre-requisites and/or spend very little time revising the prereqs. In most cases, the prereqs are glossed over in the first week of the class. If you fundamentals are shaky, it will be a lot more difficult as the class progresses and you may find yourself lost with some of the more advanced topics.

You should ideally talk to the TA of the class and try to meet with the Professor during his office hours and have an honest discussion with him to help you decide if you should take the class. Its better than playing catch up for the rest of the semester.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should make sure you have reviewed the matter of the prerequisite classes, and perhaps have relevant texts handy. But doing so in the first week of the class is probably late (depending on how rusty you are in the relevant subjects).